# Troubleshoting, is it Offtopic?

Tags: discussion

I know trouble-shooting can me made at Ubuntu forums and is a good interface to do so.

Is trouble-shooting off-topic in a Q&A site ?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: In theory ofc. I will read the community guidelines again.

Comment: @Pilot6 did you understand the question?

Comment: I did not get what you call a "troubleshooting" question.

Comment: @Pilot6 you seem to be missing a coma. As I understand this a straight to the point Q&A site.

Comment: @userDepth You really need an example because it depends on the question. A Q like "Package X does not work, how do I trouble shoot it?" Would likly7 be on topic but general, abstract, trouble shooting tips, would be to broad and off topic. You need to add some context to this.

Answer (score 6):

Troubleshooting is certainly allowed. Just don't make an answer to start the process.

We have comments for pretty much this exact reason: to ask the OP for clarification, to request more info and ask for the result of certain commands or tweaks.

However, we do want to keep comment discussions to a minimum if we can. Even though they exist as a place for some extra clutter to live without getting in the way of answers, we still want others to be able to somewhat easily read through them. This is where chat comes in. You may have noticed at some point that a comment thread might have a link to start a new chat room.

Use that link to start a chat room whenever necessary, but you don't need to listen to it. A chat room is good if the troubleshooting process is taking a while. It's basically the comment section of the comment section: somewhat hidden to avoid clutter, but still easily accessible to everyone who's interested.

To say it quickly, troubleshooting is allowed. We wouldn't be able to help people without it. You just need to do it in the right place.